# Google App Engine Datastore - retrieving data and passing to a template

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am a beginner, and am using GAE Datastore - have retrieved values in main.py and passed to template html.  I only have 2 entries in the list I'm expecting [maggie u, jerry u]

However, in my console, I see that there is escape characters -- is this why my jquery autocomplete is not working?  how do I get rid of these escape characters????  Sorry if this question is silly for you experienced people out there.  ANY help is much obliged!

Here is portion from my template html file:

```
 var myList = [u&#39;maggie u&#39;, u&#39;jerry u &#39;];
 $(function() {
    $( "#Iname").autocomplete({
        source: myList
    });
```

Comment: Please post the appropriate portions of template.html (before parsing) and main.py that renders it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you passed the list as a string, instead of a list.
Example

```
my_list = [u'maggie u', u'jerry u']   # a list with two unicode literals 
str(myList)                           # results in : "[u'maggie u', u'jerry u']"
```